# How to display sum of total order sales per product and product related information. Sql Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am beginner in Sql Server. I am facing a problem. I do have some table that are related with each other based on foreign key [image link below]. Now i want to display Product Name, Product Category Name, and total sale order per product. But when user will click button or link user will see first 10 top most sale product then on next click user will see next 10 products.

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P24B.png)

Here is the code, I tried. I am confused column to put in place of **??** .

```
    select p.product_name, c.category_name, ??
from production.products as p
    inner join production.categories as c on p.category_id = c.category_id
order by ?? desc;
```

Comment: *"But when user will click button or link user will see first 10 top most sale product then on next click user will see next 10 products."* That is application logic, not SQL. The RDBMS should be returning the entire dataset to the application, and then it should be displaying the appropriate rows from that dataset based on the "page".

Comment: View aggregate functions and table join.

Comment: Also, you `JOIN` to `production.categories` twice in the above SQL, and give it the same alias (`c`) both times. An alias must be unique within its defined scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your table structure I have come to this solution.

```
select p.product_name, c.category_name, sum(o.quantity * o.list_price * o.discount) as total_sale_per_product
from sales.order_items o
    inner join production.products p on o.product_id = p.product_id
inner join production.categories c on p.category_id = c.category_id
group by p.product_name, c.category_name order by total_sale_per_product desc
offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only;
```

Assuming that you are developing web application pass the the offset rows and fetch rows through url [query string is better option].